# How to check socket server is open?

Tags: r, sockets

I start a socket server and a connection to that server using the following R code:

```
library(svSocket)
R server: socket <- startSocketServer(port=8888)   
R client: socketcon <- socketConnection(port=8888)
```

I run a `while(TRUE)` loop in R client and would like to stop it if the socket in R server is closed by `stopSocketServer(port = 8888)`

Have tried with `isOpen` but have no luck since it returns TRUE even when i stop R server.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem sometimes when doing parallel work using `snow` and connections are not closed properly.

when you get error message about:

```
 summary.connections(connection) : Invalid connection
```

I use:

```
closeAllConnections()
```

to shut all the connections that are left open.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for you to close the socket client manually. The `svSocket` package has a `closeSocketClients` command, which is called by `stopSocketServer`. Strangely, `socketConnection` is mentioned and linked to in [the documention on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svSocket/svSocket.pdf), but there is no manual entry. There is, however, a function called `socketClientConnection`, which might be the function you are looking for. It might be that the package has seen some changes, which are not properly described in the documentation. You might want to send an e-mail to the package maintainer about this.